# Kosher nicotine replacement therapy?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, medicine

I've tried to quit nicotine cold turkey and find it difficult.  Are there any replacement therapies -- such as nicotine gum or lozenges -- that are kosher?  Aside from possible kashrut issues, are there any reasons under halacha not to use them?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Sam, and best of luck with kicking the habit!  Note that we do not claim to be Rabbis and do not offer practical halachic advice - that should be [given by your Rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146/4794). You may want to [edit] your question to remove the personal nature of it.  Hope to see you around!

Comment: @yEz I think this question is fine in its present form. The personal details aren't specific enough to make it a request for psak.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not going to bother arguing about it. Anything of the form "can I do X" is hard for me to see otherwise.  Especially when I used to get bothered for use of the word "I" in clearly hypothetical and far-fetched situations.

Comment: I've made a small edit to this question to focus it more on the kashrut of such treatments (and any other halachic considerations with their use).  I don't see a problem with the context provided by the first sentence.

Comment: I'd recommend: "Are there any nicotine replacement therapies that are kosher and permitted according to halacha"

Answer (score 1):

The CrC has a medicine list, which lists recommended and not recommended items. They list a few lozenges which are kosher, from the list they present they presently do not recommend any gums. The list should not be used after Dec 2015 (per their instruction).

Here is the [document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=OrKiVfyjA8ep-QH_1KaAAQ&url=http://www.crcweb.org/OTCMedicineReport.pdf&ved=0CDsQFjAE&usg=AFQjCNHN-HXy6vsrQvDB4WkYuugANtL1eA&sig2=bYQQ9bAbYRrJTT3zH744vQ); type 'smoking aid' into the find box and you will see the list.

Here is the list:

Nicoderm CQ Patch Patch: **Recommended**

Nicorette 2mg & 4mg Cherry Lozenge Lozenge: **Recommended**

Nicorette 2mg & 4mg Mint Lozenge Lozenge: **Recommended (dairy)**

Nicorette 2mg & 4mg Mint Mini Lozenge Lozenge: **Recommended**

Nicorette 2mg Cinnmon Surge Gum Gum: Not Recommended

Nicorette 2mg Fruit Chill Gum Gum Not Recommended

Nicorette 2mg White Ice Mint Gum Gum: Not Recommended

Nicorette 4mg Cinnamon Surge Gum Gum: Not Recommended

Nicorette 4mg Fruit Chill Gum Gum: Not Recommended

Nicorette 4mg Original Gum Gum: Not Recommended

Nicorette 4mg White Ice Mint Gum Gum: Not Recommended